# Impossible conditional statement

Tags: c++, conditional-statements

```
bool flag = ((idx == n) ? true : false);

if (C[idx]->n < t)
    fill(idx);

if (flag && idx > n)
    C[idx - 1]->deletion(k);
```

The above code snippet is part of the [BTree implementation](https://www.programiz.com/dsa/deletion-from-a-b-tree), I searched everywhere but I can't find will the second if-statement will ever be executed?

The *`flag`* will only be *`true`* when the *`idx == n`*, Right? and the if statement will execute only if *`idx > n`* and *`flag = true`*, which is impossible.

I think that the `fill(idx)` is changing value but I can't understand how? Someone explain

**fill function**

```
void BTreeNode::fill(int idx) {
  if (idx != 0 && C[idx - 1]->n >= t)
    borrowFromPrev(idx);

  else if (idx != n && C[idx + 1]->n >= t)
    borrowFromNext(idx);

  else {
    if (idx != n)
      merge(idx);
    else
      merge(idx - 1);
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: Show us the definition (or, at least, the declaration) of `fill`. If that takes its argument by reference, then it can modify `idx`.

Comment: It can be modifying `n` too.

Comment: ... looking through the (huge amount of) code in the given link, it seems that the declaration is `void fill(int idx)`, which make the code you've posted look suspect. But we shouldn't have to look through linked code: you should provide enough information **in the question itself**.

Comment: random code you can find on the internet is just that: some random code. Everybody can write a blogpost with some code, thats why there is so much rubbish out there. You are correct to think that this code looks a little odd. It should not pass a codereview. This lines are enough to know that you better read elsewhere

Comment: @AdrianMole no it's just passing n as value, the full code is available on the link mentioned

Comment: Having looked at the linked code I agree, the code makes no sense.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number On every coding site same code is given, If you have implementation for btree it will be helpful

Comment: That code is utterly garbage. It took me about a minute to dig down through `fill` and determine, yes, `n` can be modified in that codepath, so that `if` statement ***can*** go either way. That's a minute of my life completely wasted. Don't write code like that. Don't expect to learn anything about C++ from code like that.

Comment: @john Looks like one of those "multi-language" posts, where the author doesn't really know all the languages and their subtle differences.

Comment: That's unfortunate, as I usually recommend that site to beginners. At least I don't recommend it for data structures.

Comment: I dont have an implementation for a Btree. I'd expect to find a quality implementation in well tested open source libraries rather than on some "tutorial" websites

Comment: @sweenish Any site for data structures?

Comment: [CLRS](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-fourth-Thomas-Cormen/dp/026204630X/ref=sr_1_2?crid=4DNAG43E3YFJ&keywords=CLRS&qid=1658149338&sprefix=clrs%2Caps%2C136&sr=8-2)

Comment: I looked at the code.  Code needs a lot of clean up.  Seems to me you find one of the many parts of that code that needs cleaning up.  (`idx` doesn't change, but `n` may change.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After implementing my version, I get to know that the in some conditions the *`fill`* function is calling another function named *`merge`* that is changing the value of *`n`*.

> When child-node can't borrow either from left-sibling or right-sibling they will merge with the parent, Which results in a change in the value of *`n`*

```
void fill(int pos)
{
    ...

    else
    {
        if (pos != no_of_keys)
            merge(pos);
        else
            merge(pos - 1);
    }
}
```

**merge function**

```
void merge(int pos)
{
    Node *child = childs[pos];
    Node *sibling = childs[pos + 1];

    child->keys[no_of_keys] = keys[pos];
    child->no_of_keys++;

    for (int i = 0; i < sibling->no_of_keys; i++)
    {
        child->keys[i + t] = sibling->keys[i];
        child->no_of_keys++;
    }

    if (!child->leaf)
        for (int i = 0; i < sibling->no_of_keys + 1; i++)
            child->childs[i + t] = sibling->childs[i];

    for (int i = pos; i < no_of_keys - 1; i++)
        keys[i] = keys[pos + 1];

    for (int i = pos + 1; i < no_of_keys; i++)
        child[i] = child[pos + 1];

    no_of_keys--;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

After looking at the code from the link you provided, the variable `idx` is never changed. But, by going through `fill(idx)`, `n` gets modified in certain cases (as it's an attribute, and as `fill` is a method that have access to `n`).
So the second `if` statement can be triggered in some cases, when `n` is modified by `fill` or one of the methods called by `fill`.

The code:

`fill(idx)`:

```
void BTreeNode::fill(int idx) {
  if (idx != 0 && C[idx - 1]->n >= t)
    borrowFromPrev(idx);

  else if (idx != n && C[idx + 1]->n >= t)
    borrowFromNext(idx);

  else {
    if (idx != n)
      merge(idx);
    else
      merge(idx - 1);
  }
  return;
}
```

It can call `borrowFromPrev`, `borrowFromNext` or `merge`, which functions can change n in some cases:

```
// Borrow from previous
void BTreeNode::borrowFromPrev(int idx) {
  BTreeNode *child = C[idx];
  BTreeNode *sibling = C[idx - 1];

  for (int i = child->n - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    child->keys[i + 1] = child->keys[i];

  if (!child->leaf) {
    for (int i = child->n; i >= 0; --i)
      child->C[i + 1] = child->C[i];
  }

  child->keys[0] = keys[idx - 1];

  if (!child->leaf)
    child->C[0] = sibling->C[sibling->n];

  keys[idx - 1] = sibling->keys[sibling->n - 1];


  child->n += 1; // here
  sibling->n -= 1; // here

  return;
}

// Borrow from the next
void BTreeNode::borrowFromNext(int idx) {
  BTreeNode *child = C[idx];
  BTreeNode *sibling = C[idx + 1];

  child->keys[(child->n)] = keys[idx];

  if (!(child->leaf))
    child->C[(child->n) + 1] = sibling->C[0];

  keys[idx] = sibling->keys[0];

  for (int i = 1; i < sibling->n; ++i)
    sibling->keys[i - 1] = sibling->keys[i];

  if (!sibling->leaf) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= sibling->n; ++i)
      sibling->C[i - 1] = sibling->C[i];
  }

  child->n += 1; // here
  sibling->n -= 1; // here

  return;
}

// Merge
void BTreeNode::merge(int idx) {
  BTreeNode *child = C[idx];
  BTreeNode *sibling = C[idx + 1];

  child->keys[t - 1] = keys[idx];

  for (int i = 0; i < sibling->n; ++i)
    child->keys[i + t] = sibling->keys[i];

  if (!child->leaf) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= sibling->n; ++i)
      child->C[i + t] = sibling->C[i];
  }

  for (int i = idx + 1; i < n; ++i)
    keys[i - 1] = keys[i];

  for (int i = idx + 2; i <= n; ++i)
    C[i - 1] = C[i];

  child->n += sibling->n + 1; // here
  n--; // here

  delete (sibling);
  return;
}
```

Comment: Can you mention the exact code path where this happens? Just want to make sure you're on the same track as me, when I mentioned this, in comments, a little while ago?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik • *That's a minute of my life completely wasted.*  Now it'll be two minutes.

Comment: I don't know, seems worth it to potentially call a bluff. An edit with the requested information will also improve the answer, whether @qdesmettre initially came across the same information or not.